# Linking a page in a multilanguage website

Tags: localization, entry, structure, multi-environment

Currently i am using this approach for linking to a entry(single page) of a structure, for example a cta button on the homepage which links to the contact page.

```
{% cache %}
    {% set single = craft.entries.id('14').first() %}
    {% if single %}
        <a class="button button--full t-spacing" href="{{ single.url }}">{{ "Neem contact op" | translate }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endcache %}
```

Or for example a "read more" button next to some results of some structure without a index. Because thats set in the structure "pages" as a entry type.

But i feel like this is somewhat hacky..
Of course you can link to a page like so:

```
{{ url('contact') }}"
```

or

```
href="{{ "contact"|translate }}
```

But url() doesn't translate and what if the slug is changed by a user of the CP.
So what is the usual way to get around this, are there any best practises?
So far i can only think of linking all the individual buttons/links to entry fields in the CP, which the user has to fill in.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a [Twig macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) to get the localized URL from an entry ID. Import it from _layout.html for example.

```
{% macro urlFromId(entryId) %}
    {%- set entry = craft.entries.id(entryId).first() %}
    {{- entry ? entry.url -}}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as macros %}
```

Then use this more concise code everywhere in your templates.

```
<a class="button" href="{{ macros.urlFromId(14) }}">{{ "Neem contact op"|t }}</a>
```